# how to stop this background

Tags: html, css

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fvus9/) code :

```
<a class="botton_menu" href="#">first</a>
<a class="botton_menu" href="#">second</a>
<a class="botton_menu" href="#">third</a>

a.botton_menu
{
    padding:0 14px 0 7px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:50px;
    line-height:45px;
    background-color:#FF0000;
    color:#781a77;
    margin-bottom:3px;
    height:46px;
    letter-spacing: -3px;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
}
```

and I'd like to have that red background color as long as the text, not until the screen size (display:block).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on having your `a` elements `display:block` you need to have them `float:left` and then clear them. Then the background/element will be as long as the content.

Comment: Just what I was about to write. Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fvus9/1/

Answer (score 3):

The `display:block;` is what it causing it to stretch out like that.

Solutions:

1. Change from `display:block;` to `display:inline-block;` (or even use the default, `display:inline;` what's the reason for you setting it to `block` in the first place?)
2. Use `float:left;`.
3. Manually set the `width` property.

Obviously the third option only works if you know what width you want. The other two solutions will cause the elements to be positioned next to each other, rather than stacked. In both cases, you'll need to tell the next element to drop onto the next line.

With `display:inline-block;` or `display:inline;`, this can be acheived with a line feed; either a hard-coded `<br>` tag, or in CSS, using the `:after` selector, and adding a line feed there. With `float:left;`, you'd need to add use `clear:both;`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create an element in the a element: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fvus9/3/)

```
<a><span>foo</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `display:inline-block;` and put `<br/>` between  tags, **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/fvus9/8/)** will solve your problem.